# Find the absolute font-size of a relative font-size

Tags: css

I use em as units for my fonts in combination with body {font-size:12px} (an absolute number, can be 20px or 14px...)

That works fine, but if I have multiple nested things,
like

```
h4{
font-size:2em;
}
h4 span{
1.6em;
}
.parent_elementofthespan span.superspan{
font-size:1.3em;
}
.basecamp3rdpartyclass h4.span{
font-size:1.9!important;
...
```

Now, things get pretty complicated in calculating the actual absolute font-size of .parent_elementofthespan span.superspan for example.

Is there any chance of "seeing" the absolute font-size within a tool or something besides calculating it manually?

Comment: I am not sure I understood you correctly. Are you asking for a tool , which will tell the font size of a span or div ?

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools (pressing F12). There you can see the calculated values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Chrome Dev tools

**F12 > Elements > Computed > font-size**

A value in pixels will be displayed.

Comment: The similar steps apply to Firefox and other browsers as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **rem** unit wherever possible.
rem is relative to `:root` font size (html element in HTML but it could be `<svg>` or  in other cases) so no hard calculations!
In a nutshell, it's em without the cascade and 95% of the time it's what you need in your CSS.
Its compatibility is IE9+.

---

**CSSViewer** (a Firefox/Chrome extension) is way faster for checking font sizes (and other typographical properties like font weights and line heights, also color) on elements one after another than DevTools/Inspect.

- [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cssviewer/ggfgijbpiheegefliciemofobhmofgce)
- The original [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/cssviewer/) (has worked flawlessly for years BUT last update was 9 years ago: it may not work on Firefox 57+ coming in a few days :( RIP)

[image]